# How to get user's operating system via Graph API?

Tags: operating-system, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get the device used by the user for login. I am able to fetch the user's details via Audit Logs in Graph API using this query:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns

```
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx",
            "createdDateTime": "2023-03-16T10:31:57Z",
            "userDisplayName": "xxxxx",
            "userPrincipalName": "xxxxx",
            "userId": "xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx",
            "appId": "xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx",
            "appDisplayName": "xxxxx",
            "ipAddress": "xxxx.xxx.xx.xxx",
            "clientAppUsed": "Browser",
            "deviceDetail": {
                "deviceId": "",
                "displayName": "",
                "operatingSystem": "Windows 10",
                "browser": "Edge 111.0.1661",
                "isCompliant": false,
                "isManaged": false,
                "trustType": ""
            },
     ]
```

I want to only get the operatingSystem under the deviceDetail but I cannot filter it in my query. Can anyone help me find the right query to get the user's operatingSystem? Thanks!

Comment: You are talking about filtering, so it's not clear for me but I guess that you want to reduce the response and return only `"value": [{"id":"xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx","deviceDetail": {"operatingSystem":"xxx"},{...}]`

Comment: Hi @user2250152, yes I'm trying to filter only the operatingSystem but I cannot find the right query. I'm only testing in on graph explorer.

Answer (score 0):

To get the operating system of a user via Microsoft Graph API, you can use the deviceManagementManagedDevices endpoint. This endpoint provides information about the managed devices associated with a user, including their operating system.

Here is the sample code using the Microsoft Graph JavaScript client library :

```js
// Initialize the Microsoft Graph client
const client = MicrosoftGraph.Client.init({
    authProvider: (done) => {
        // Authenticate using the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL)
        // See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-javascript
        // for more information on how to authenticate using MSAL
        done(null, accessToken);
    }
});

// Get the managed devices associated with the specified user
client
    .api(`/users/{userId}/deviceManagement/managedDevices`)
    .version('beta')
    .get((err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }

        // Filter the list of devices to find the device that is currently being used by the user
        const currentDevice = res.value.find(device => device.deviceName === '{deviceName}');

        // Check if the current device was found
        if (currentDevice) {
            console.log(`Operating system: ${currentDevice.operatingSystem}`);
        } else {
            console.log('Current device not found.');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi @Abhijeet Jadhav Is there a way to do the query on graph explorer? I don't have a js application and currently testing it on the MS Graph Explorer only.

Comment: GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/managedDevices  & GET /deviceManagement/detectedApps/{detectedAppId}/managedDevices/{managedDeviceId}/users/{userId}/managedDevices   . Pl note - The Microsoft Graph API for Intune requires an active Intune license for the tenant.

Comment: This is fetching the managedDevices in Azure AD. I don't have any managed devices. I want to get the deviceDetails from the sign-in logs using this query: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns

Comment: Currently only these query parameters are supported - $top, $skiptoken, and $filter. So Graph explorer would give you the entire response and not the specific property. You would need to use some additional code to get the exact details. You can find the latest details here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http